# Regex to find words that contains these letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex to find some words that contains some letters.
I have the word `start`, and by regex it should find words that contains (s, two t's, a, r), that has at least 3 letters. So it should return all these words:
`start`, `tarts`, `arts`, `art`. So it should be at least three letters and contains only those characters (s, two t's, a, r).

I tried something like this:

```
/(([^s]*s){1})(([^t]*t){2})(([^a]*a){1})([^r]*r){1}/g
```

But this regex does not work, since it requires to be all in this order.

I also tried this one:

```
[star]{3,}
```

But it matches any number of characters inside `[]`, ex it matches `sss`

Comment: There's no nice way to do what you want. Regex has some limitations and sometimes you should use plain coding to test some specific corner cases. Is there any reason it **needs** to be a single Regex?

Comment: @ciencia, anubhava just wrote the right regex to make this work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use this regex with 2 negative lookahead assertions:

```
/\b(?!\w*([sar])\w*\1)(?!(?:\w*t){3})[sart]{3,}\b/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IWzXSU/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary assertion
- `(?!\w*([sar])\w*\1)`: Negative lookahead to assert we don't have more than one instance of `[sar]` letters
- `(?!(?:\w*t){3})`: Negative lookahead to assert we don't have more than 2 `t` letter
- `[sart]{3,}`: Match 3+ characters containing `[sart]` characters

Comment: It will match 'stt'

Comment: Yes and `stt` should be a valid match

Comment: @anubhava this is what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your time and effort

Answer (score 0):

Not a fun answer, but the double t really makes this difficult. This may be possible with some complicated back referencing...but a more brute force solution would be to write some code to select all options in put them into a capture group separated with |'s.

a la: (start|art|tart|tra|trat|...)

Definitely not pretty, but this would work.